# Of Nazis and Zombies

Tags: magic, warfare, weapons, zombies

It's 1942 and the Nazis finally perfected a weapon which will change the war : **Die Früherwaffe**

This weapon basicly is some kind of mathematical-magic-powered weapon that allows you to cast spells. It's easy to use and was designed to be used by pretty much any member of the German army. The only requirement is to have a special mark that acts as a unique identifier that unlock the weapon.

Most spells mimic the effects of modern gear, they can work as radars, GPS, guns, smoke grenades, medkit. These spells are cool but they dont offer much innovation and cant be considered a serious advantage in the war.

But the most wicked Nazi's scientist designed a very complex spell that seems to have a lot of potential. You guessed it, a zombification spell.

Before asking anything let me tell you how it works.

> **Früherwaffen buchstabieren : Zombieshaffung**
>
> ***Usage :***
>
> 1. Load the "Zombieshaffung" cartridge into your Frühergewehr.
> 2. Aim toward a dead body at a maximum range of 100 meters
> 3. Congratulations ! You just gave that body a new chance to serve the Reich !
>
> ***Commanding your Zombie :***
>
> Your zombie will only respond to orders he has been taught. To provide a combat-ready solution, the Reich pre-programmed your zombie with a set of basic orders. Here is a non-exhaustive list of pre-programmed orders :
>
> *GO TO, CARRY, FOLLOW, FETCH, WALK, RUN, STAY, SLEEP, LOOK OUT FOR, ATTACK, PROTECT, EAT, DIE, OBEY TO, USE, ATTACH*
>
> Zombies will obey to identified German soldiers and consider all other hot-blooded creatures as hostiles if ordered to *ATTACK / PROTECT* a zone. You can tell your zombie to only execute orders given by a defined identified subject (or group) using the *OBEY TO* command.
>
> If you have any issue with your zombie or need to have a new order programmed, ask a Früherscientist.
>
> ***Summary on Zombie metabolism :***
>
> Zombies don't need any food, the EAT command was mainly given to have them take care of waste (Bodies or other) and for your enjoyment.
>
> The only way to kill a zombie is to destroy the mark that was branded on the body as part of the creation process. Any body part severed from the mark will lose all animation. We therefore recommend to put the mark somewhere on the torso or head.
>
> A reattached bodypart (even if it was not the original one) will start functioning again. We highly encourage you to customize and repair your zombie by changing body parts regularly. To do that, simply ask your zombie to do so. If your zombie is unable to perform the task, you may do it yourself by roughly reconnecting bodyparts using staples, wire or rope. The zombie will take care of the rest.
>
> **Q&A**
>
> *- Do zombies feel pain ?*
>
> It's irrelevant.
>
> *- What are zombie's vulnerabilities and resistances ?*
>
> Zombies are particularly vulnerable to fire and are resistant against crushing, shrapnel, toxins and small to medium caliber bullets.

Considering all I've written, here are my questions :

- **Can this weapon REALLY change the war (As in the German winning) ?**
- **How should these zombies be used by the Germans forces ?**
- **Reasons why German troops would find using that weapon ethical.**

Comment: Read Max Brook's _Zombie Survival Guide_ the Recorded Attacks section covers the use of Zombies in an attempt to win WWII, spoiler; it ends badly.

Comment: Magic has just happened, and you ask "will this be significant?". I am figuratively sitting on my right hands now in order to not yell out a big, fat, caps locked, bolded, emphatic affirmative in this comment. Yes of course it will be significant. All of those things will be **very** significant for the outcome of the war. Yes of course they are advantages. They are **huge** advantages. Also: here we have another case of "[I have a cool concept, now please work out the consequences](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/)". We do not do that here. You have to do that.

Comment: @MichaelK, Got It, I thought about that too. Do you think there is anything I could salvage from here ? or should I better just nuke the question to oblivion ? (And maybe go post it on reddit and see where that leads me.)

Comment: @LéonDonnet-Monay Why not play around a bit with the concept in chat and brainstorm with people? :) Welcome to [The Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor).  :)

Comment: Too broad, and opinion based. Voting to close. Only you know how things would turn out in your universe. Too many what-ifs

Answer (score 2):

**- Can this weapon REALLY change the war (As in the German winning) ?**

From  your description, it seems that only German soldiers will be able to be turned into zombies. What happens if an Allied soldier gets hit? Does he become a thrall of the Germans or will he retain the hatred for the German, thus attack the soldier.

If only German soldiers can become obedient zombies then the advantage will still be big but not huge as opposed to anyone getting hit by this ammunition being a German zombie.

Imagine D-Day or big battles like Moscow. We're talking about an infinite supply of soldiers here. Soldiers that become more durable after being zombified. I can see the advantage as being **huge**.

**- How should these zombies be used by the Germans forces ? Reasons why**

So many uses. Firstly, they can be a meat-shield against enemy fire. Depending on the durability of these zombies, they can be used to soak fire until the real troops reach an advantageous position. They could be dropped possibly without parachutes behind enemy lines and cause havoc. Another use would be to spread disease. Decaying bodies spread death and a few hundreds of zombies, although "killed" would create great problems for the enemies.

**- German troops would find using that weapon ethical.**

That ones is a toughie. If you consider the spiritual aspect of things, are you trapping the soldier's soul in his body to animate the corpse? That would create a massive ethical/spiritual dilemma for many soldiers. Another aspect is creating a hulk of meat out of your former comrade. That could have been your friend or brother that you're zombifying, imagine the feelings there.

German soldiers, or any soldiers in general follow orders. In the later stages of the war, the German troops were also mostly filled with young men that just did what they were told. I cannot see how this can be an ethical thing unless in your version of history all Germans are super villains. But I don't see it.

The only way to make this fly on an ethical level, is to add a special division in the German military, the Zombifiers, that would be specialist zombie makers. Only they were equipped with those weapons. They could even be a secret division that would integrate with the main army. Those men could easily be unscrupulous with 0 ethics since it would be voluntary to join.

Comment: Infinite? Um no, just no.

Comment: My first worldbuilding answer, cut me some slack!

Comment: You do know you can edit such gaffs out when people point them out right?

Comment: Actually I thought you meant something else since English is not my mother tongue. Is it the use of the word "infinite" in this context? Is it not correct? Seeing as soldiers that die, get zombiefied and after sustaining damage drop and can possibly still be zombified to keep on fighting, the use of the word infinite here seems fitting. What sort of gaff are you referring to?

Comment: Yeah infinite means literally never ending. You can in fact subtract an infinite number from an infinite number and still have an infinite number. Any gaff, sorry "gaff" is also an old term for mistake.